# Hide launch parameters from process name in .net Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, parameters, process

I have a multi-platform C# console application, and I have an issue where the process name shows the launch parameters(args) the progrm was launched with. This only occurs on Linux and not on Windows.

For example:
If I start my program with `./MyProgram -u username -p password`
The entire launch command is shown as the process name in process monitoring applications such as Screen or TMUX.
Is there any way to redact this information from the process name without switching over to prompting the user for these parameters during runtime?

PS: I know fully well about passing sensitive information unencrypted as launch parameters, but since this software isn't really that serious, I dont need a lecture on encrypting variables within memory. I'm just trying to tackle these safety concerns one at a time.

Comment: Very strange that you can't see these parameters in Windows - https://serverfault.com/questions/323795/display-complete-command-line-including-arguments-for-windows-process

Comment: On windows you have to explicitly specify if you want to see the launch params in your process name.